# Как перенести базу

Tags: mysql

Как перенести базу с mysql 2.6.1 на 5?

Answer (score 4):

Сделать резервную копию через [mysqldump](http://www.blog.shops.kharkov.ua/utilita-mysqldump-i-shpargalka-po-parametram/), и развернуть ее через [mysql](http://mysql.ru/docs/man/mysql.html).
В самом простом варианте - резервная копия. Обращаемся к mysql 2.x через параметры (хост, порт, юзер, пароль, имя базы):

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password= databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

И, восстановление. Обращаемся к серверу mysql 5.x через параметры хост, порт, юзер, пароль, имя базы для этого сервера:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password= databasename < dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: у вас скайп есть мне надо по подробнее

Comment: куда уж тут подробней ? )

можно без промежуточного файла :)

mysql -u root dbname -ppassword < mysqldump -u root -ppasword dbname